# How to confirm an action using a modal window in JSF?

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I have a JSF MyFaces dataTable that contains a list of elements and a column with a delete button. All I want to do is to popup a dialog when clicking on the delete button that would allow the user to confirm or cancel the operation.

I already have the dialog (reduced for simplicity and using `<a>` because of the lack of HTML5 support):

```
<div id="myModal">
    <h:form>
        <a data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <h:commandLink action="#{somethingMagicInHere?}">Confirm</h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

In the dataTable I have something like this (also simplified):

```
<h:dataTable id="myDataTable" value="#{bean.elementList}" var="element">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Actions</f:facet>
        <a class="call-modal">Delete</a>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Finally my ManagedBean looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@RequestScoped
public class ElementClassBean {
    ...

    public String actionToPerform(ElementClass e) {
        MyBusinessLogicModel.getInstance().deleteElement(e);
    }
}
```

So, in short, jQuery executes when loading the page and takes all elements with class `call-modal` and sets an `onclick` to them so that they display the component with id `myModal`, which is of course the modal window. I inherited this working this way and prefer not change it but any solution or ideas will help.

I can use a `commandLink` directly in the dataTable that would access `actionToPerform(element)` from the view but that, of course, won't fire the modal. So the main issue I see, given this structure, is how can I send the `element` being iterated in the `dataTable` to the modal once the `Delete` button is clicked? (I don't mind if the solution uses Ajax).

Any input will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Lack of HTML5 support? Huh? Your code is already in HTML5 syntax?

Comment: @BalucC Unless I'm missing something, I can not use an `<h:link>` and add also a `data-*` HTML5 attribute. AFAIK, I'd have to create a new renderer for that to work. That's why I'm using `<a>`

Comment: Why exactly do you need `<h:link>` instead?

Comment: I don't need it. But as this is a JSF project I thought that it would be a would idea to turn all `<a>` into `<h:link>`. In this case it doesn't seem to be key to do so as it seems to be just a link that is assigned some jQuery code based on the `data-dismiss` attribute. Anyway, I think rendering an `<a>` using pure HTML or JSF  is not relevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is the ugly but working solution that doesn't require me to refactor all the views and managed beans. In short: I added a hidden input field that would store the id of the element to delete in the modal form. In the datatable all I do is setting the value of the hidden input field once the button is clicked and fire the modal. The modal is then filled with the just updated value.

My simplified modal:

```
<div id="myModal">
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.elementIdInModal}" id="elementIdInModal"/>
        <a data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean[actionToPerform]}">Confirm</h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

My simplified dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable id="myDataTable" value="#{bean.elementList}" var="element">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Actions</f:facet>
        <h:link styleClass="call-modal"
            onclick="$('#myForm\\:elementIdInModal').val(#{element.id})">
            Delete
        </h:link>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

My simplified ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@RequestScoped
public class ElementClassBean {
    private long elementIdInModal; // Ommiting getters and setters

    public void actionToPerform() {
        MyBusinessLogicModel.getInstance().deleteElement(elementIdInModal);
    }
}
```